# Editing questions after initial post?

Tags: support, edits

Is it possible to edit your questions after your initial post? The reason I ask is I've seen myself and others mess up and not be able to reach their 'true' question to the audience that can help them.

Comment: The only possible mistake you could make is not trying it.

Comment: I believe the relevant sentence from the the [ask] help center page is: *If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it.* So editing is not only very possible, but definitely encouraged if necessary (and within the guidelines explained by Matt in his answer).

Comment: As for the "is it possible" part, the simple technical answer is the [edit] link just below the question on the left (only visible when you are logged in; trying it now from an incognito window, I get a "pending edit" warning when I click the link in this comment.  If you are not logged in, you only see the [share](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298798/874188) link below the question's tags).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can edit your post to clarify the question you are asking. What you **shouldn't** do is edit your question such that it invalidates any existing answers to your question.

If it becomes apparent that you asked the wrong question, but have already received answers then **ask a new question**. Consider including a link to the old post to give the new post some context. If any of the answers to your old question helped lead you on the path to enlightenment, don't be against accepting it.

If you repeatedly see yourself having to refine your questions, I'd suggest you might want to spend more time debugging and trying to diagnose the problem more **yourself**, before you come to Stack Overflow for support. Doing this helps to make you initial question more refined, as you have a greater understanding of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow is basically an archive of good answers. A good answer usually needs a good question.

Aim to get your question well polished - make it clear what it's asking, as easy as possible to reproduce, test and understand, and you've done the first and most important part of enabling a good answer.

Revising your question to improve it is never a bad thing. There are plenty of people who have edit capability who can do minor fixes, but the only person who really understand what you're asking is you.

The fact that *you* might get a good answer to your question is actually more like a beneficial side effect. What we really want is answers that help everyone.

So edit and polish your question until it gleams. And if you find that you were asking the wrong thing.... open a new one. We like questions here, especially the shiny gleaming ones that elicit good answers.