# Question significantly edited by one answerer - My answer is now useless

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, edits

This morning I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096915). It had a [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) tag and even though he did nothing in his code except to import it I've provided an answer that builds on the NumPy library. The other answerer provided an answer based on pure Python.

After the other answer was accepted, he deleted the [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) tag and the numpy import from the question. So my answer is pretty obsolete now and I'm a bit undecided what I should do now:

- Delete my answer.
- Rollback the question.
- <strike>Scream at the other answerer in the comments.</strike>

I hope you could advise me on the best course of actions here.

Comment: You could add a disclaimer add the top of your answer: *As you initially did import numpy and tagged it as such I thought there is no harm in providing an answer using that library.* or similar wording

Comment: Meta effect in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: I agree that the tag should not have been removed, if it was already there. Still, even if the tag wasn't there in the first place, adding a numpy-based solution can be reasonable, as it's fast and clear. It could only be less helpful if OP is explicitly *not* using numpy, in which case importing a bulky module like that can be problematic.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298798/editing-questions-after-initial-post

Comment: @AndrasDeak, rene - That seems reasonable, I'll edit the answer so that it makes it clear numpy is an alternative in this case. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: @MSeifert It's a known "effect" where an increased number of eyeballs on a linked post (on Meta) result in an influx of votes (up/down/close/delete/etc). I was simply stating my observations as your post has so far received an additional 3 upvotes (it could be argued that they were unrelated due to the post's age).

Comment: @Sam Maybe I'm just too suspicious. I've suspected the other answerer to invalidate my answer by editing the question and after reading on the meta-effect I thought your comment meant that I intentionally asked the question here to get more upvotes. I didn't intended that, I only linked to the question to give some context for this question without repeating it. Maybe that's another question but is linking to the own questions/answers on meta considered bad style?

Comment: No, quite the contrary. If you asked this "hypothetically", somebody is sure to write a comment asking for a specific question where it applies to. The Meta-effect is unavoidable; readers *are* going to inspect the question to see what's it all about, and some *are* going to use that opportunity to up or downvote as they see fit. Depending on the general direction of votes, the Meta-effect has been called either a blessing or a curse.

Comment: @MSeifert No no, not at all; that was not my intent. Rad's comment sums it up quite well.

Comment: Doubtlessly, meta is the best place to get fast rep. ["_I'M LOVIN' IT_"](http://oi64.tinypic.com/axfprt.jpg)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would say that the original question should not have been tagged numpy. The reason is that the user clearly didn't understand what numpy is and probably tagged it so because the base code included it. So the edit is appropriate.

Your answer isn't invalidated by this (it looks like a solid answer), but I would rewrite it so that it offers numpy as an alternative and comment that the original question asked for a numpy answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems on the same lines as the others: to edit my answer. Instead of the options I considered so I'm very happy I asked the question.